# Get documentId from newly created document in flutter and firebase app

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to get the document ID of a newly created document in Cloud Firestore so I can use it in another place immediately after.

I have followed a post here but my situation is a bit different.

When I save the client data into the client collection creating a new document. do this  by calling the "save" function in the Notifier Provider and from there I call the "save" function in the firestore class.

Here is the code:

```
Client Screen: 
if (ref.read(clientNotifierProvider).clientId == null ||
                          ref.read(clientNotifierProvider).clientId == "") {
                        ref
                            .read(clientNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .saveClient(ref.read(clientNotifierProvider), true);
                      } else {
                        ref.read(clientNotifierProvider.notifier).saveClient(
                            ref.read(clientNotifierProvider), false);
                      }
```

ref.read(clientNotifierProvider.notifier).saveClient:

```
if (isNewTrxn == true) {
      firestoreService.saveNewTrxn(toMap(newTrxn), companyId);
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewTrxn(false);
    } else {
      firestoreService.saveTrxn(toMap(newTrxn), companyId,
          ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentTrxnId!);
    }
```

Saving the client data to Firestore:
Here client is just the client notifier provider that has been populated with all the client data.

```
Future<void> saveNewClient(client) async {
    // Get the document ID of the new document so it can be
    // added to the new transaction document.
    DocumentReference docRef = await _db.collection('client').add(client);
    return client.updateClientId(docRef.id);  <<< BREAK POINT HERE
  }
```

I set a breakpoint but execution never stops at the line and the docRef.id is never inserted into the client data model.

How do I get the document ID so I can insert it into the client data?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I added the try/catch but it is not throwing an error.

```
 Future<void> saveNewClient(client) async {
    // Get the document ID of the new document so it can be
    // added to the new transaction document.
    try {
      DocumentReference docRef = await _db.collection('client').add(client);
      return client.updateClientId(docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

How do I get the document Id?

Comment: Try to catch exception by enclosing you db calls in try/catch block. So you can know the exact error.

Comment: I added the try/catch but there is no error. The line where I want to add the clientId to the client provider is not working.